# Jquery modal not appearing on success form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple modal that will appear when a user successfully submits a contact-7 form on my WordPress site. Although submissions are successful, the bootstrap modal is not appearing. Can be inspected at [Delta Designs Contact Page](https://deltadesigns.co/?page_id=43)

The error I receive is below, but I'm unsure of where it's referring to as it all seems in order. I had it working, but can't seem to find what I've broken.

Thank you for any assistance!

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

The bootstrap modal

```
  <div class="modal-fade" id="submitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="submitModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title" id="submitModalLabel">Success!</h3>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Thanks for reaching out! We'll reply within 1-2 business days.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="https://deltadesigns.co/"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Back to Home &raquo;</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  <?php add_action('wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer');
  function mycustom_wp_footer()
  {
  ?>

    document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
      if ('86' == event.detail.contactFormId) { // Change 123 to the ID of the form 
        jQuery('#submitModal').modal('show'); //this is the bootstrap modal popup id
      }
    }, false);


<?php  } ?>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click',
    function() {
      document.querySelector('.modal-fade').style.display = 'none';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Syntax errors will always tell you the exact file and line they're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

you wrote querySelector in the 3rd to last line without specifying where to select :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  <?php add_action('wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer');
  function mycustom_wp_footer()
  {
  ?>

    document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
      if ('86' == event.detail.contactFormId) { // Change 123 to the ID of the form 
        jQuery('#submitModal').modal('show'); //this is the bootstrap modal popup id
      }
    }, false);

</script>
<?php  } ?>
```

into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  <?php add_action('wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer');
  function mycustom_wp_footer()
  {
  ?>

    document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
      if ('86' == event.detail.contactFormId) { // Change 123 to the ID of the form 
        jQuery('#submitModal').modal('show'); //this is the bootstrap modal popup id
      }
    }, false);

<?php  } ?>
</script>
```

Your closing script tag should be on the outside of your PHP function because the opening is also on the outside. What's happening is you have an opening `<script>` tag inside another opening `<script>` tag